# Send values to the database, don't insert duplicates

Tags: c#, webmethod

In need to check if value from TextBox is already in database and if it is not to save it again in the database.

This is the TextBox code:

```
 <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblProductConstruction" runat="server" Text="Product Construction:" Font-Names="Open Sans"></asp:Label></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductConstruction" runat="server"  Font-Names="Merriweather" margin-Left="100px" ></asp:TextBox><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

Save button:

```
<input type="button" class="button" id="myButton" value="Save"/>
```

Ajax on button click:

```
 $(function () {

             $('#myButton').on('click', function () {

                 var lvl = $('#MainContent_txtProductConstruction').val()

                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "NewProductConstruction.aspx/GetCollection",

                     data: JSON.stringify({'lvl': lvl }),

                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",

                     success: function (response) {
                         alert("Saved successfully.");
                         console.log(response);
                         location.reload(true);

                     },
                     error: function (response) {
                         alert("Not Saved!");
                         console.log(response);
                         location.reload(true);
                     }

                 });

             });

         });
```

WebMethod that takes the value and sends that parameter(@ObjekatName) to the database:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static void GetCollection(string lvl)
        {

              string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand("getDuplicate", connection);
                    cmdCount.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ObjekatName", lvl);
                    cmdCount.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    int count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmdProc = new SqlCommand("InsertObjekat", connection);
                        cmdProc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmdProc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ObjekatName", lvl);
                        cmdProc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //strMsg = "Saved successfully.";
                    }

                }
                catch
                {


                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();

                }

            return;
```

First procedure is a select that try's to find value in the database.
If this select finds something then Count has to be greater than 0 and this should close connection.
And if select does not return anything than this new value must be inserted in the database.

I have executed and tested these stored procedures and they work fine.
The problem is in C# i think I did something wrong here and this is not working correctly.
Can someone help me with c# part ?
BTW: Ajax works fine and values are taken by WebMethod correctly

Thanks in advance !

Comment: can you please provide procedure

Comment: Found the solution, but thanks !

Comment: so what is issue ???

Comment: When there is no value in the database it returns NULL and this code helped
if (count == null) then insert new values.

Comment: in stored proc you can do like this `if exists(select * from table)begin select 1 end else begin select -1 end`...remember null is not suggested way ...you can handle in db easily and code you written will work as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there might be problem with this lines of code

```
 cmdCount.ExecuteNonQuery();
  int count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
```

as per this it command two time one `executenonquery` and then `executescalar`,

as per your requirement there should be only one call which is `ExecuteScalar`, so comment out `ExecuteNonQuery`

```
  //cmdCount.ExecuteNonQuery(); comment not needed 
  int count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: I did this but with success.
It can go past if (count > 0) the problem is that Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @freej17 - can you show you procedure 'getDuplicate'..that helps to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two execution from C#, you can check the duplicate and insert the values in same procedure.

```
            CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getDuplicate (ObjekatName IN VARCHAR2)
            AS
               V_COUNT   NUMBER;
            BEGIN
               SELECT   COUNT (1)
                 INTO   V_COUNT
                 FROM   TABLENAME
                WHERE   CatName = ObjekatName;

               IF (V_COUNT = 0)
               THEN
                  **-- insert command**

               END IF;
            END;
```