# Show alert from C# code

Tags: c#, ajax, webforms

This is a WebMethod that takes value from front-end in the lvl string.
Later that string is checked through getDuplicate procedure if there is already that value in the database. If the value exists then the insert porecedure InsertObject is not activated and if there is no such value in the database frist procedure returns null and the insert procedure will work.

Everything work well in the code all I need is some kind of a alert message from C# part of the code if the insert is success, and if it fails.
I tried so many examples and I can't find any solution :/
Can someone please help ?

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static void GetCollection(string lvl)
        {

    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))

        try
        {

            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand("getDuplicate", connection);
            cmdCount.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ObjekatName", lvl);
            var count = (string)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();


            if (count == null)
            {
                SqlCommand cmdProc = new SqlCommand("InsertObjekat", connection);
                cmdProc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmdProc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ObjekatName", lvl);                   
                cmdProc.ExecuteNonQuery();
              //successful alert
            }
            else
            {
              //fail alert
            }
        }


        catch 
        {


        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();

        }

    return;

    {
}
```

Update:
Ajax that sends values to the method:

```
$(function () {

             $('#myButton').on('click', function () {

                 var lvl = $('#MainContent_txtProductConstruction').val()

                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "NewProductConstruction.aspx/GetCollection",

                     data: JSON.stringify({'lvl': lvl }),

                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",

                     success: function (response) {
                         alert("Saved successfully.");
                         console.log(response);
                         location.reload(true);

                     },
                     error: function (response) {
                         alert("Not Saved!");
                         console.log(response);
                         location.reload(true);
                     }

                 });

             });

         });
```

Comment: I guess you'll have to return some kind of JSON structure with your response on it and manage to show that info to the user in the web side by using javascript to interpret the response and present the alert.

Comment: A `WebMethod` should return the client-code(in your case some javascript-alert). It can´t return `void`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere A `WebMethod` named GetSomething should return something ;-)

Comment: Is there some kind of a way to send JavaScirpt alert directly from C#, or some similar kind of a alert ?

Comment: That deends on what your webmethod is supposed to do. In case of it returning a string, you may just use `return "alert(...)"`.

Comment: We need to see how you're calling this method.

Comment: Ok, here's the ajax:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167861/send-values-to-the-database-dont-insert-duplicates/51167953?noredirect=1#comment89320405_51167953

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the webmethod return type

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static int GetCollection(string lvl)
{
int success=0;
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))

    try
    {

        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand("getDuplicate", connection);
        cmdCount.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ObjekatName", lvl);
        var count = (string)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();


        if (count == null)
        {
            SqlCommand cmdProc = new SqlCommand("InsertObjekat", connection);
            cmdProc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdProc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ObjekatName", lvl);                   
            cmdProc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            success= 1;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }


    catch 
    {


    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();

    }

return success;

}
```

}

Do some small change in Jquery Code

```
       $(function () {

         $('#myButton').on('click', function () {

             var lvl = $('#MainContent_txtProductConstruction').val()

             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "NewProductConstruction.aspx/GetCollection",

                 data: JSON.stringify({'lvl': lvl }),

                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",

                 success: function (response) {
                     if(parseInt(response.d)>0)
                        alert("Saved successfully.");
                     else
                        alert("Not Saved!");
                     console.log(response);
                     location.reload(true);

                 },
                 error: function (response) {
                     alert("Not Saved!");
                     console.log(response);
                     location.reload(true);
                 }

             });

         });

     });
```

Comment: Sorry but this example is not working :/
Massage is not shown on the fron-end, and page is not reloaded after success.

Comment: change parsInt to parseInt. And try again. Syntax Issue

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thanks allot ! :)